# how to "mix" two numbers into one hex-string

Tags: math, cryptography

How to generate a code from two numbers, that when you know this code and one of the numbers you can descramble the second number?
For example you have two numbers: `983` and `2303` and you "mix" it into hex-string like this:`4b17a190bce4ea32236b98dd`. When you know first number and this hex-string you can descramble second number. But when you know the second number and hex-string you cannot descramble first number. How to do this?

Comment: do you mean something more complicated than just adding them?

Comment: Looks a lot like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832494/what-is-this-string . Try adding details to the original question, it can get reopened if it makes sense...

Comment: it depends on the "mix" algorithm

Comment: You're onto something, Mr Diffie...

Comment: There's always the Intercal # (mesh) operator.

Comment: What's wrong with a decent block cipher? The first number is used as the key. The second number is a plaintext block. "Mix" is encryption. If you know the ciphertext and the key (first number), then you can get the second number. But when you know the ciphertext and plaintext (second number) then you cannot get the key.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and really NONSAFE (as in dead easy to crack by anyone paying a bit of attention) method of doing it:

```
 int number1;
 int number2;
 int key;

 //encode  (we know number1 and number2 and we want to know the key)
 number1 = 983;
 number2 = 2303;
 key = number1 ^ number2;

 //decode  (we know number1 and the key and we want to know number2)
 number1 = 983;
 number2 = key ^ number1;
```

Yet again (to avoid downvotes). This method is cracked in seconds by anyone who sits down for it.  It does work for clueless users (clueless as in, no math or programming background).

Answer (score 0):

You need something like XOR: you xor the two numbers and store the result and one of them. Then you xor the result with the number you know and get the other number back. Not all operations will do for this purpose of course.

Answer (score 0):

In python:

```
hash = 0x4b17a190bce4ea32236b98dd # hash
input = 983
output = 2303

#k = hash - (input * output)
k = 23239944001398166727313395124

def decode(hash, input):
  return (hash - k) / input

def encode(input, output):
  return '%x' % (k + (input * output))

print k, decode(hash, input), encode(input, output)
```

Comment: This answers the OP's question quite literally.  Any punishment for weak encryption should be on the question, not the answer.

Answer (score -1):

**ENCRYPTION:**

1. SHA1-hash the first number

   This gives a 20-byte output (or 40-char hex string if you prefer).
2. Use this hash to build an AES key (E.g. use the first 16 bytes to get a 128-bit key).
3. AES-encrypt the string : (in your example 983:2303) using this derived key [Use AES CBC encryption]
4. Output will be a 32-character hex string

**DECRYPTION:**

1. Step 1 and 2 as above:

   Note: This is only possible if you have the first number, not the second number
2. AES-decrypt the input hex string

   This gives :
3. Answer is number after the colon.